# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot format given Object as a Number

Tags: java

I need to display 2 decimal point but I don't get it how to do It.

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot format given Object as a Number

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class ShoppingOrders {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double itemPrice, shippingFeeRate, shippingFee,totalCost;
        String nameItem;
        Scanner myScanner= new Scanner (System.in);
        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.00");
        
        nameItem = myScanner.nextLine();
        itemPrice = myScanner.nextDouble();
        shippingFeeRate = myScanner.nextDouble();
        
        shippingFee =shippingFeeRate*itemPrice;
        totalCost = shippingFee+itemPrice;
        
        System.out.println ("Costs for "+nameItem);
        System.out.println (df.format("Item Price: $" +itemPrice));
        System.out.println (df.format("Shipping Fee: $"+ shippingFee));
        System.out.println (df.format("Total Cost: $"+totalCost));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using `DecimalFormat.format(...)` incorrectly. You don't pass it a `String`. You pass it an object that represents a number. (Or a primitive number type which will be boxed to an object that represents a number.)

For example:

```
df.format(itemPrice)    // itemPrice will be boxed to a Double
```

So if you want to include a message in the output, you might do this:

```
System.out.println("Item Price: $" + df.format(itemPrice));
```

Alternatively, you could use `String.format(...)` and specify the number of digits after the decimal point in the format specifier.

Answer (score 0):

`DecimalFormat.format(...)` is for formatting a number. In your case, you added a String to the double, which turns it into a `String`, which `DecimalFormat.format(...)` doesn't support. Instead, use:

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Main{
public static void main(String[] args) {
    double itemPrice, shippingFeeRate, shippingFee,totalCost;
    String nameItem;
    Scanner myScanner= new Scanner (System.in);
    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.00");
    
    nameItem = myScanner.nextLine();
    itemPrice = myScanner.nextDouble();
    shippingFeeRate = myScanner.nextDouble();
    
    shippingFee =shippingFeeRate*itemPrice;
    totalCost = shippingFee+itemPrice;
    
    System.out.println ("Costs for "+nameItem);
    System.out.println ("Item Price: $" +df.format(itemPrice));
    System.out.println ("Shipping Fee: $"+ df.format(shippingFee));
    System.out.println ("Total Cost: $"+df.format(totalCost));
}
}
```